# Regex to detect when certain characters or substrings

Tags: html, regex

I'm currently using a regex to detect space, single-quote & double-quote in an input.

I would like to add the detection of several strings: ex. 'xxx' & 'yyy'. It should only detect for those complete strings, so 'x' or 'y' by itself wouldn't be detected.

Currently have this in html input code:

```
<input type="text" pattern="^(?=.*[\x27\x20\x22]).+$" ...
```

Comment: `pattern="^(?=.*[\x27\x20\x22]).*(xxx|yyy).*$"`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  I tried it - the xxx & yyy is working but now the space/'/" isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to ensure exactly one space, single-quote or double-quote appears in the input, you can simplify your pattern to:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[\x27\x20\x22]" ...
```

To detect other things, you can add "alternations", separated by `|`:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[\x27\x20\x22]|xxx|yyy" ...
```

As per jhnc: To detect any instance, no matter where in the string:

```
<input type="text" pattern=".*([\x27\x20\x22]|xxx|yyy).*" ...
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I tried your pattern and it's not working - I've set up a jsfiddle - hopefully you can tell me what's wrong. Test by changing value="" to something jsfiddle.net/billparti/x0t7k5sn

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? If I delete the value="xxx" and all the CSS, run, and just type into the textbox, I see the expected browser highlighting.

Comment: By the way, if you want to match something like "hello xxx.123" and not precisely " " or "xxx", etc, then you will need to put back the `.*` at the start and end: eg. `pattern=".*([\x27\x20\x22]|xxx|yyy).*"` as patterns are implicitly wrapped with `^` and `$`

Comment: If you mean that "Pattern Match" is never displayed, it's because the .warn div is not a child of input. Try changing the css selector to `... ~ .warn` or `... + .warn` or somesuch. cf. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Yep, I needed the additional code ( the third suggestion) is now the accepted answer - thanks